# Mix-&-Match of 3 COVID-19 Vaccines?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, vaccine

Now that getting the third shot of COVID-19 vaccine is allowed, which one of the following order of 3 vaccines will lead to better protection and more robust immune system response against Covid-19 and its variants? And how many weeks must be between the 1st & 2nd shots and the 2nd & 3rd shots?

1. Oxford–AstraZeneca + Pfizer–BioNTech + Oxford–AstraZeneca
2. Oxford–AstraZeneca + Oxford–AstraZeneca + Pfizer–BioNTech
3. Oxford–AstraZeneca + Pfizer–BioNTech + Pfizer–BioNTech

The first dose/shot in all 3 cases is 'Oxford–AstraZeneca' due to the findings of this published article in the magazine of Nature: https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-01805-2.

Comment: Although this isn't an exact duplicate of your question, the accepted answer comes very close. https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/28770/how-does-getting-2-or-3-shots-of-the-pfizer-or-moderna-covid-vaccine-compare-aga

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does getting 2 or 3 shots of the Pfizer or Moderna COVID vaccine compare against 1 shot Johnson & Johnson's vaccine + 1 shot of Pfizer or Moderna?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/28770/how-does-getting-2-or-3-shots-of-the-pfizer-or-moderna-covid-vaccine-compare-aga)